# Very slow MySQL query (20 to 60 seconds! ) - why?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, performance

I have an issue with the following query. It selects log records from a database table.

```
SELECT  paymentslog.*, user.username, user.usergroupid, user.displaygroupid,
        purchase_temp.threadid
    FROM  " . TABLE_PREFIX . "paymentslog AS paymentslog
    LEFT JOIN  " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user AS user
       ON (paymentslog.userid = user.userid)
    LEFT JOIN  " . TABLE_PREFIX . "paymenttransaction AS paymenttransaction 
       ON (paymentslog.transactionid = paymenttransaction.transactionid)
    LEFT JOIN  " . TABLE_PREFIX . "paymentinfo AS paymentinfo
       ON (paymenttransaction.paymentinfoid = paymentinfo.paymentinfoid)
    LEFT JOIN  " . TABLE_PREFIX . "purchase_temp AS purchase_temp
       ON (paymentinfo.hash = purchase_temp.hash) $filterlogs_where
    GROUP BY  paymentslog.logid
    ORDER BY  paymentslog.dateline DESC
    LIMIT  $startat, $perpage
```

- all the joins are needed to access threadid on SELECT except the join with user table to access username, usergroupid and displaygroupid
- it was needed 20 seconds to run (!), and during my try to fix it, after add of INDEX for column transactionid (of table paymentslog), now it needs... 60 seconds!
- for some reason, it was return a specific row multiple times, and for this reason I fixed it by add a "GROUP BY paymentslog.logid"

I have to notice that:
- $filterlogs_where PHP variable has the WHERE of the query (I build via php different filters for the paymentslog).
By default, $filterlogs_where has a value of "1 = 1", and if I have to apply a filter, I add a .= " AND paymentslog.userid = X" etc etc.

Any idea why this query is so slow?
I think I have seen and write more complicated queries which runs in a few seconds or milliseconds. Why this issue with the above query?

Comment: While joining on hash is possible, joining just on integers should be a lot faster. How much data are we talking about, you neglected to tell us that.

Comment: Joining on integers may be fractionally faster, but that's all. It's impossible to help with this problem without CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables and an EXPLAIN for the above query

Comment: @Xorifelse - There is no `HASH` index.  Anyway, Hash is only marginally faster than BTree.

Comment: If the tables are large, the optimizer may be able to do better if you do ANALYZE TABLE (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/analyze-table.html) on each of the tables.  You may also want to do an EXPLAIN (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html) on this select to see if it is altering the order of tables in the joins at all.  Usually listing the smallest table first, if the optimizer isn't able to get table size information, helps a series of joins go faster. EXPLAIN will also let you see where it is using indexes (or even if it is).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I must admonish you not to have multiple tables with the same schema.  That is usually a bad design.

Do you really need `LEFT`?  That is, you want a row returned even when the 'right' table has nothing?  If not, simply use `JOIN`.

Getting rid of the `LEFTs` may get rid of the `GROUP BY`.  Joins followed by `GROUP BY` usually cause "inflate the number of rows" followed by "deflate via group by".  This creates a huge temp table in the process, thereby slowing things down.

Then I need to point out that [*Pagination via Offset*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/pagination-optimization/) is problematic -- often leading to lengthy query times.  However, we need to get rid of the `GROUP BY` to make this technique possible.

Please use shorter aliases.

Now, back to your specifics...  Well, first work on the stuff above.  And supply `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.  Then something like this will speed things up:

```
SELECT ...
    FROM ( SELECT id
               ORDER BY  dateline DESC
               LIMIT  $startat, $perpage ) AS pl
    JOIN user ON ...
    JOIN ...
    ORDER BY dateline DESC;   -- yes, needs repeating
```

Comment: Hello Ricky and thank you very much for the analytical reply! As I could understand with your example, I wrote the following query: http://pastebin.com/GQAWe9AZ       Is that correct? It seems return correct results with lots of records, but with a test with 2 records, no one appear. Sorry for the long aliases, will fix them soon.

Comment: Perhaps you do need `LEFT`.  (I don't understand the _intent_ of the query.)